# Asymptotics of Laplace transform and asymptotics of probability measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, asymptotics, laplace-transform

I know that for a sequence $(p_n)_n$ with $\sum_{i\geq 1} p_n=\infty$ there is a strong relation between the asymptotic behaviour of $p_n$ (or at least $\sum_{k=1}^n p_k$) for $n\to\infty$ and the asymptotic behaviour of the Laplace transform $\mathfrak L_{ (p_n)_n}(\lambda)$ for $\lambda\rightarrow 0$. At least for $p_n$ decaying like $n^{\alpha-1}$ for some $\alpha>0$ one has good asymptotics by some Tauberian Theorems (see i.e. Feller Vol. 2).

Now let's think of a probability measure on $\mathbb N$ which of course satisfies $\sum_{n\geq1} p_n =1$ and also $\sum_{n\geq 1} n p_n = \infty$. One could now compute at least the asymptotics of
$$1- \mathfrak L_{(p_n)_n} (\lambda), \quad \lambda \rightarrow 0. \quad (*)$$

But my question is the other way round. Assume we know the asymptotic of $(*)$ and want to know something about the asymptotic behaviour of $p_n$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$. Is there any relation? At least if we have that for some constant $C>0$ and $\alpha>0$
$$1- \mathfrak L_{(p_n)_n} (\lambda)\sim C \lambda^{\alpha}, \quad \lambda \rightarrow 0$$
holds?
Maybe that for some constant $\tilde C$
$$1-\sum_{k=1}^n p_k = n^{-\alpha} \tilde C$$
holds?

All the best

Comment: So I have $1- \sum_n p_n e^{-nx} \sim x^{\alpha}$ for $x\rightarrow 0$. If I integrate that from 0 to x I get $x+\sum_{n} p_n/n e^{-nx} - \sum_n p_n/n$ and get $x+\sum_{n} p_n/n e^{-nx} - \sum_n p_n/n \sim ~ x^{\alpha+1} *C$ for $C=\frac{1}{1+\alpha}$. Especially that gives me that $\sum_{n} p_n/n e^{-nx}~ C x^{\alpha+1}$, right? But how can I apply a Tauberian Theorem to that?

Comment: Mhhh, but how does that help if I only know the asymptotics of $1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n e^{-nx} $ for $x\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Ok I took it the wrong way. You want to know the asymptotic of $\sum_n p_n n e^{-nx}$, if you are lucky this is just the derivative of the asymptotic of $\sum_n p_n (1-e^{-nx})$ but sometimes you might be unlucky. Usually it works when you know the asymptotic of $\sum_n p_n (1-e^{-nx})$ not only for $x>0$ but for $\Re(x)>0,|\Im(x)|<T$ then the asymptotic of the derivative is the derivative of the (analytic) asymptotic thanks to the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I feared. I mean somehow it is the other way round than l'Hospital. And I fear the only usable condition under which it holds is if $p_n$ is monotone?

Comment: Mhhh, so maybe I should look at the Fourier transform?